# Does generator power cord gauge have to be the same as the power inlets gauge?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I wired my generator inlet power box with 8 gauge to a 50amp breaker in my box. Can I use a 6 gauge power cord to connect my generator to that inlet power box? Will this cause any issues or power loss? I’m having trouble finding a generator power cord that’s 8 gauge 50 amps. My generator runs 9500 watts. Thanks for any help with this question.

Answer (score 2):

9500 watts is about 40 AMPS at 240v. 8 gauge is good for 40 amps even in a cable. You can always use wires that are larger than needed, but not less.  Think thru this...most of the wiring in your house is probably 14 ga, or 12 ga. yet you are seldom using anywhere near that much on each circuit.  Same applies to your generator connection.   You might be slightly undersized for a larger generator, but for what you have now, you should be fine.